# select_related models field comparison

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have looked up on the Internet but it is quite possible that I did not know exact keywords to look for. Without any further ado, the question.

I have models roughly as following in my models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_book_count = models.IntegerField()
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    book_serial_number = models.IntegerField()
    # Field above keep track of order in which book was written
    # value of 2 mean that it was second book author wrote and so on
```

In my query, I can easily do following

```
queryset = Author.objects.filter(author_name__icontains = "john").select_related('book')
return_data = queryset.filter(book__book_count = x).values('book__book_title')
# Gives me xth book of all authors in the queryset
```

## Problem:

I want to latest books of the authors, i.e., `author_book_count == book_serial_number`, so what filter should I be using in my queryset.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbling here and there and trying various combinations of search terms, I learned about [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) which solves the problem I intend to solve nicely. Approximately the approach would be as following.

```
return_data = queryset.filter(book__book_serial_number = F('author_book_count')).values('book__book_title')
```